# Multiple level subdomains SSL certificates

Tags: apache, security-certificate

I have a need for multiple subdomains to have a SSL certificate.

For instance, the following where the subsite number and subsubsite number could go for ever.

- `subsite1.sites.example.com`
- `subsubsite1.subsite1.sites.example.com`
- `subsubsite2.subsite1.sites.example.com`
- `subsubsite3.subsite1.sites.example.com`
- `subsite2.sites.example.com`
- `subsite3.sites.example.com`

Without creating a separate certificate for each subsite, how can this be implemented?

Comment: Buy wildcard SSL certificate for parent domain. That should work for all sub-domains.

Comment: @NikhilSupekar  I have done so, but it only works for one level (i.e. example.com and subsite1.example.com, subsite2.example.com, ...)

Comment: ohh!! I had never tried that. In that case, for above example, you can buy a separate SSL for example.com and wildcard SSL for *.sites.example.com and *.subsite1.sites.example.com, so 2 wildcards and 1 normal SSL certificate should be enough.

Comment: I'd question why you need so many levels of subdomains, and whether can be brought up to a single subdomain level. Moving to a directory-based structure on a single subdomain could actually be more friendly SEO & usability.

Answer (score 1):

I hear that you can use a UCC certificate for multiple hostnames on multiple domains, but I haven't found anyone that will issue one with wildcards (I'd love to be proven wrong on that).

Each wildcard certificate can only be used for one level of subdomains.  You will have to purchase another wildcard certificate for each subdomain where you want subsubdomains.

I have the same problem, so I feel for you.

See also: 
[Problems with SSL and multi level subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295521/problems-with-ssl-and-multi-level-subdomains?rq=1) 
[Wildcard SSL certificate for second-level subdomain](https://serverfault.com/questions/104160/wildcard-ssl-certificate-for-second-level-subdomain) 
[Wildcard SSL Certificate registration with multi-level subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192200/wildcard-ssl-certificate-registration-with-multi-level-subdomains?rq=1)

Those questions probably belong here, but I don't think this site existed back when those questions were first asked.

Comment: Thanks James.  Bummer!  Could I purchase `*.sites.example.com` with addition level `*.*.sites.example.com`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can buy `*.sites.example.com` and `*.subsite1.sites.example.com`, but I've never done so, so I'm not sure how the ownership validation would work given that there isn't a Whois record for the subdomain.